# Products list sorting order

Tags: magento-1.8, product-list, sorting

I have a list of products with 3 attributes (Date, among others) to sort by. By default the sorting is an ascending order, is there a way to change it to be a descending order instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change it simply in the backend, however you can edit the `local.xml` file and add the following depending on your needs

Location of that file is here normally:

> app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout

```
<layout>
    <catalog_category_default>
      <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
          <action method="setDefaultDirection"><string>asc</string></action>
      </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>

    <catalog_category_layered>
      <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
        <action method="setDefaultDirection"><string>asc</string></action>
      </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>

    <catalogsearch_result_index>
      <reference name="search_result_list">
        <action method="setDefaultDirection"><string>asc</string></action>
      </reference>
    </catalogsearch_result_index>
    <catalogsearch_advanced_result>
      <reference name="search_result_list">
        <action method="setDefaultDirection"><string>asc</string></action>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_advanced_result>
</layout>
```

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: Klettseb do you know how to do this in M2.x? I have created an attribute but magento sorts on the first digit instead of the whole integer. E.g. order is 1, 11, 2.
While it should be: 1, 2, 11.