# Product Sorting in Category Page

Tags: product, category, sorting

When I am landing in a Product Category Page I am getting the sorting order Descending Direction like below. I need this only at "Sort By Name" but not in others.

[image]

But I would like to have Ascending Direction when I am landing a Product Category Page like below one.

I need this only at "Sort By Name" but not in others.

How can I do that ?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Products list sorting order](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115914/products-list-sorting-order)

Answer (score 2):

You can set the default sort order of your category in the local.xml of your theme:

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="product_list">
        <action method="setDefaultDirection"><string>asc</string></action>
        <action method="setDefaultOrder"><string>position</string></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

Similarly you can add code for `<catalog_category_layered>` and `<catalogsearch_result_index>` also.

Please let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Thank @Mohit Kumar Arora. But I could not find your code snippet in my **local.xml**  file. I am using Shopper Default Theme. Thanks

Comment: If this code snippet does not exist in your theme's local.xml, then you need to add it.

Comment: Thank @Mohit Kumar Arora for your reply.Your solution is not working. Thanks